# How to start sending BCCMD commands to a CSR 8675 audio chip?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I am having trouble understanding how to send BCCMD commands to a CSR 8675 audio chip

For example, I would like to try out the bluecore commands described in the [Audio API design document by CSR](http://www.52bluetooth.com/csr/adk4.0/adkdocs/vm/libraries/CS-209064-DD.pdf)

I have ADK 4.0.1 installed as well as Bluesuit 2.6, and the standard 8675 development board provided by CSR (H13179v2)

I have found CSR documents that describe a BCCMD command structure, but not a simple explanation on how to get started with actually sending BCCMD command

I would like to know what I need to get started using basic commands, such as chip reset, firmware version read, and other audio API commands such as stream_get_source

Comment: Do you have the CSR8675 datasheet?

Comment: @DrCachetes yes